# how to link text field data between two views?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, textfield, uitextfielddelegate

Hi and thanks in advance for any responses.

I'm working with two UIViews with the Ipad. If the user makes changes to the text field in one view, I want those changes to appear in the textfield of the other view. 
I have one text field in each view.
In IB, I gave them the same tag and textfield delegate. I only have one IBOutlet but I dont think it possible to connect to both text field?
I tried IBOutletCollection but it doesn't support textfields.
I don't know where to go from here?What should I do?
Any advice is appreciated!thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is bindings an KVO(Key-Value-Observation). The idea behind this is: One object observes changes of another object's property.

Have a look at [KVO and Bindings on iPhone](http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2010/04/kvo-and-bindings-on-iphone/) on Mindsizzlers.com or take a look at the book Cocoa Design Patterns Chapter 32 Bindings and Controllers.

Comment: yes of course, but this is the proper way. It will make your code more readable. You can also use notifications to inform your textfields that somethinh changed. I'd rather put the string in a model class so there is only one place for the value to exist. the textfield merely read and write the model class/property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UITextField delegate methods to detect text changes in one text field and update the other. The method below gets called every time a character is typed in one of the textfields (provided you have set your view controller to be the UITextField delegate):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // Here you can run your logic to detect which textField has changed (using tags)
    // And update them accordingly.
}
```

Comment: ye I have this delegate method already.how would I update the other textfield without having to make another textfield declaration in my interface?